# Is $x=\infty$ considered or not as a solution to $\exp(-x)=0$?

Tags: exponential-function

Is $x=\infty$ considered or not as a solution to $\exp(-x)=0$ ?

If not, why?

Comment: It depends on the set where you are looking for solutions. If the set is $\mathbb{R}$, then the answer is no.

Comment: $\infty$ is not a number, therefore it cannot be a solution of the equation—which simply has no real solution. In fact, the notation $x=\infty$ is a little misleading; you should think in terms of limits: $\exp(-x) \to 0$ as $x\to\infty$.

Comment: @Naja "$\infty$ is not a number" doesn't make sense. Which numbers are you claiming it is not one of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a solution in the real numbers.  ($\infty$ is not a real number.)

It is not a solution in the complex numbers.  ($\infty$ is not a complex number.)

It is not a solution in the Riemann sphere $\overline{\mathbb C}$: Yes,
$\infty \in \overline{\mathbb C}$, but $\exp(-x)$ has an essential singularity at $x=\infty$.

---

So it is best just to say
$$
\lim_{x\to +\infty} \exp(-x) = 0
$$
and not $\exp(-\infty) = 0$.

An important property of the exponential function is $\exp(z) \ne 0$ for all $z$.